# pandas how to draw graphs from a dataframe by group， but group number is uncertain

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this：

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataA = [["Abc", "8:05", 5], ["Abc", "8:10", 8], ["Abc", "8:15", 7],
    ["Abc","8:20", 4], ["Abc", "8:25", 2], ["Abc", "8:30", 2],
    ["Axy", "8:05", 15], ["Axy", "8:10", 6], ["Axy", "8:15", 1], 
    ["Axy", "8:20", 11], ["Axy", "8:25", 12], ["Axy", "8:30", 7], 
    ["Aeq", "8:05", 12], ["Aeq", "8:10", 8], ["Aeq", "8:15", 3], 
    ["Aeq", "8:20", 7], ["Aeq", "8:25", 15], ["Aeq", "8:30", 14]]

dfa = pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["An", "coltime", "Val"])
```

in this sample it only 3 group ：Abc  Axy Aeq
in real data ，colum An has uncetain group number， and how to draw line graph ？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) first:

```
df = dfa.pivot('coltime','An','Val')
```

---

**df:**

| An | Abc | Aeq | Axy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coltime |  |  |  |
| 8:05 | 5 | 12 | 15 |
| 8:10 | 8 | 8 | 6 |
| 8:15 | 7 | 3 | 1 |
| 8:20 | 4 | 7 | 11 |
| 8:25 | 2 | 15 | 12 |
| 8:30 | 2 | 14 | 7 |

```
df.plot()
```

Comment: I just came across : https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# so was testing that. Hence edited the answer. Just sharing this awesome tool :D if not known already.